# How to remove string numbers with regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have this string, I want to remove numbers that have two decimal places and also three decimal places, however, for numbers that contain two decimal places, I don't want to remove the first two numbers that are in the string, this is my code.

```
import re
string = "air max 12 x clot infantil 16 26 67 80 272 117 160"
regex = re.sub(r"\d{3}", "", string)           
print(regex)
```

Well, notice that I can eliminate numbers that have 3 decimal places, but those that contain two I can't.  Even if my code is this:

```
import re
string = "air max 12 x clot infantil 16 26 67 80 272 117 160"
regex = re.sub(r"\d{2,3}", "", string)           
print(regex)
```

This works, the problem is that it will remove the first two numbers that have two decimal places, the output I wanted was:

```
import re
string = "air max 12 x clot infantil 16 26 67 80 272 117 160"
regex = re.sub(r"\d{2,3}", "", string)
//something here
print(regex)
Expected output
air max 12 x clot infantil
```

How can I do this using regex?

Comment: in your example there are no decimal places in the string for the numbers, did you mean a length of 2 or 3?

Comment: You're right, I was wrong in the term of decimal places, but I think I could more or less understand the question, if I can't edit

Comment: @etch_45 yes I meant it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following regex: `'[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z]'`, it will match anything starting from alphabet and ending on alphabet.

```py
>>> re.findall('[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z]', string)
['air max 12 x clot infantil']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but I don't want to leave it in a list `[]`

Comment: Just take the first item from it.

Comment: I didn't mention it in the question, but I'll have many items, and there's no way for me to know all the indexes, although I can go through the list with `for`, do you have any solution for this?  +1

Comment: You can just iterate the list, or you can just use `re.finditer` to get an iterator of matches and iterate over them. Also it'd be better to add such a example that matches *I didn't mention it in the question, but I'll have many items*

Comment: Obs, I noticed that if I change the string to "air max 90" it only displays "air max" why does this happen?

Comment: Because for your example, it is expected to start from a string character upto the last string character, the text "air max 90"  doesn't actually match the sample data you have in the question.